# GO API with SQLITE3 can't DELETE tuple from db

Tags: sqlite, rest, go

Hello fellow developers.
I am trying to learn `GO` while constructing a simple web API using `sqlite3`. I got stuck at somepoint where i am unable to delete rows from my table by sending a `DELETE` request from postman. I am trying to use the code below to delete a row. I have already verified that I have access to db and I can also delete rows by using command tool of sqlite3. I do not understand what is wrong!

```
func deleteArticle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    params := mux.Vars(r) // get any params
    db := connectToDB(dbName)
    defer db.Close()

    _, err := db.Query("DELETE FROM article WHERE id=" + params["id"])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "article couldn't be found in db")
    }
}
```

Here is the navigation part:

```
myRouter.HandleFunc("/articles/{id}", deleteArticle).Methods("DELETE")
```

**No mather what I do I cannot delete an article from db using postman**.
Thanks bunches.

[image: postman]
[image: delete_method]

Comment: What is the output of `fmt.Printf("%q\n", params["id"])`? Also what is the response that you get back? Are you getting an error, or does it just return `200` but the record's still in the database? Please provide more information so that we can help.

Comment: Meto please also note, that it is **very important** that you do *not* use `Query` nor `QueryRow` for SQL queries that do not return any rows, for these cases use the `Exec` method. When you use `Query` you always have to assign the result to a non-blank identifier, i.e. anything but `_`, and then invoke the `Close` method on that once you're done with the result. If you do not do that then your application will leak db connections and very soon will start crashing.

Comment: *Another very important* thing is that when you want to pass user input (including record ids) to your queries you have to utilize, at all times, the parameter-reference syntax supported by the sql dialect and/or dirver you are using, and then pass the input separately. That means that you should never do `Exec("DELETE FROM article WHERE id=" + params["id"]`), instead you should always do `Exec("DELETE FROM article WHERE id= ?", params["id"])`. If you do not do it the proper way and instead continue using plain string concatenation your app will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: ... here's an example, directly in the go-sqlite3 package's tests, that shows how the parameter-references are used: https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/b4f5cc77d1cca1470922e916c9f775ef17d2d78f/sqlite3_test.go#L587

Comment: Thank you very much. Really valuable suggesstions. I will apply them right away. `fmt.Printf("%q\n", params["id"])` returns "2" and I have a tuple in db which has ID of 2. Note that I am keeping IDs(primary key) as integers. Can this oppose a problem?

Comment: Right after I started using Exec method, I was able to fix the problem. Thank you very much :D .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva) 's comments I have learned that

1.

> It is very important that you do not use `Query` nor `QueryRow` for SQL
>   queries that do not return any rows, for these cases use the `Exec`
>   method. When you use `Query` you always have to assign the result to a
>   non-blank identifier, i.e. anything but `_`, and then invoke the Close
>   method on that once you're done with the result. If you do not do that
>   then your application will leak db connections and very soon will
>   start crashing.

2.

> when you want to pass user input (including record ids) to your
>   queries you have to utilize, at all times, the parameter-reference
>   syntax supported by the sql dialect and/or dirver you are using, and
>   then pass the input separately. That means that you should never do
>
> `Exec("DELETE FROM article WHERE id=" + params["id"])`,
>
> instead you should always do
>
> `Exec("DELETE FROM article WHERE id= ?",params["id"])`
>
> If you do not do it the proper way and instead continue
>   using plain string concatenation your app will be vulnerable to SQL
>   injection attacks.

Regarding this information I have changed my code into:

```
func deleteArticle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    params := mux.Vars(r) // get any params
    db := connectToDB(dbName)
    defer db.Close()
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", params["id"])
    statement, err := db.Prepare("DELETE FROM article WHERE id= ?")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "article couldn't be found in db")
    }
    statement.Exec(params["id"])
}
```

Which has solved my problem. So thank you [@mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva)